# ng-bootstrap Datepicker current date like placeholder

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I use ng-bootstrap Datepicker something like here: [plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/wwbmDw23bkKdqc8zvdDG?p=preview)

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
         name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
  <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="d.toggle()" >
    <img src="img/calendar-icon.svg" style="width: 1.2rem; height: 1rem; cursor: pointer;"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I would like have placeholder as current date instead yyyy-mm-dd.
For example today 23.10.2016.
It is possible or how can i do that.

Comment: What do you mean by " actual day"? Current date? It is not clear what you want to have displayed....

Comment: sorry yes current date for example today 23.10.2016

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do like this-

In component, defined date like this-

```
valuedate = new Date();
```

In template html, change placeholder like this-

```
placeholder="{{valuedate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}"
```

Result:

[image: date placeholder]

Comment: i need in value